# How to get last entered textdata from textfile?

Tags: c#

Does any one know how to fetch last entered textdata from textfile any one know

```
var Readtxt = File.ReadAllText(@"D:\file\log.txt");
```

Comment: Define "Last entered", you mean the last line?

Comment: Do you mean *the last line* `var lastLine = File.ReadLines(@"D:\file\log.txt").Last();` or *the last edit* (which is impossible)

Comment: Last Modify , insert text in textfile

Comment: Impossible... but you can save data everytime you changed log by appending date or something else appending in name like "log-2542016" etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple answer: it's *impossible* unless you have *prior version* of the file.
Imagine, that the file is

```
  A
  B
  C
```

what's happened before? Is it `A` added or `D` removed or `B` changed from `E`?
If you have a previous version you can compute so called *edit distance*, e.g.:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance

```
Before After
  A      A
  C      B
         C
```

Edit distance (Levenshtein one) is `1` and the *edit operation* is `B inserted`. However, even *edit distance* doesn´t guarantee the *exact editing procedure*, but it provides the *most probable one*.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to determine that, without knowing the previous version. If you have the previous version, you could count the lines added or even make a diff based on both the inputs.

Windows can [keep previous file versions](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/previous-versions-files-faq#1TC=windows-7), but I haven't found a way yet to retrieve that version.